# UnSupported Exception in ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

I  was implementing a program to remove the duplicates from the 2 character array. I implemented these 2 solutions, Solution 1 worked fine, but Solution 2 given me UnSupportedOperationException. Why is that so? The error is at line `al1.removeAll(al2);`

```
public void getDiffernce(Character[] inp1, Character[] inp2){

    // SOLUTION 1:
    // **********************************************

    List<Character> list1 = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(inp1));
    List<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(inp2));
    list1.removeAll(list2);

    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println("***************************************");


    // SOLUTION 2:

    Character a[] = {'f', 'x', 'l', 'b', 'y'};
    Character b[] = {'x', 'b','d'};

    List<Character> al1 = new ArrayList<Character>(); 
    List<Character> al2 = new ArrayList<Character>(); 
    al1 = (Arrays.asList(a)); System.out.println(al1);
    al2 = (Arrays.asList(b)); System.out.println(al2);  
    al1.removeAll(al2);         // error is here     
    System.out.println(al1);
}
```

Comment: What is the line number referenced in the exception stacktrace? Which line here does it correspond to?

Comment: Please do not cross post to different sites on stack exchange.

Comment: It says 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:144)
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:360)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(AbstractCollection.java:337)
 at dominator.Dominator.getDiffernce(Dominator.java:111)
 at dominator.Dominator.main(Dominator.java:23)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `asList(..)` documentation:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.

Basically the `asList` method does not create a normal mutable `List<E>` but a wrapper around an array. The `remove` operation is hence not available on a list which is backed by an array.

Try to build your lists by manually constructing them:

```
List<Character> al1 = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(a))
```

So that the backed list is used only to initialize a real `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed-size list. No entries can be added or removed.

You can work around this by:

```
al1 = new ArrayList<Character>((Arrays.asList(a)));
```

and the same for `al2`.

This is already happening in the top solution.

in the second, you create an ArrayList then overwrite it with the fixed one, instead of filling it, keeping in mutable.

Comment: al1.addAll((Arrays.asList(a))); al2.addAll((Arrays.asList(b)));  The addAll() worked for me.

Comment: @JNL I'm proposing another method. That is also valid.

Comment: True...Agree with your method. It just got me thinking about the addAll() method. Nonetheless all the above answers helped me to learn more about the method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use `Arrays.asList()`. And this type of list is *not* modifiable.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) explicitly says so:

> Returns a **fixed-size list** backed by the specified array. [emphasis mine]